# Installed kernel headers and $(uname -r) differ

Tags: raspbian, kernel, apt, driver

Raspberry Pi 1 Model B.

If I run:

```
uname -a
```

I get: 4.9.16+

Gcc version: 4.9.2

If I execute:

```
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

it installs me 4.4.50+

Why and how can I install the version of my linux kernel?
(I need to build some Wifi Dongle drivers source code)

Comment: I suggest you restore the Foundation supported (and tested) firmware and kernel and use that rather than the latest bleeding edge kernel/firmware.

Comment: @Milliways can you help me in finding the version? What I did right now I updated raspberry pi to the 4.4.50+ version to match the headers. What you are talking about is even older or this is ok? Maybe some link? Thank you!

Comment: Managed to compile the driver for the dongle DLINKGO GO-USB-N150, after updating to 4.4.50+ and headers also, and fixed some compilation bugs!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can restore your system to standard with 
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel`

`sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers` should then install the appropriate headers.